# Dot Net Core Web api on RHEL8 with nginx proxy returns 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: .net-core, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to run dot net core 5 “web api” in Red hat linux 8 server with nginx proxy setup.

The steps I took are as follows

Step 1 –
I created sample web api application “webapp3” using Visual Studio 2019 (weather app) on local windows10 ,  using dot net 5 and tested, it works fine. It returns the json response.
Then I published the application to a local folder

Step 2 -
Then I configured a new EC2 RHEL 8 instance in AWS , installed dot net core 5
Also, created folder /var/www and used below command to make ec2-user owner of the folder
sudo chown -R -v ec2-user /var/www

Step 3 -
Using scp copied the published folder from local windows folder to /var/www folder in the ec2 instance

Step 4 -
I created the systemd service as follows

```
sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/webapp3.service

[Unit]
Description=Example .NET Web API App

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/Webapp3.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then I started the service with following commands

```
sudo systemctl enable webapp3.service
sudo systemctl start webapp3.service
sudo systemctl status webapp3.service
```

Then I opened a duplicate terminal in putty and ran below command

```
curl http://localhost:5000
```

I got proper json response with weatherforecast json output

Step 5 –
Installed nginx and started nginx , confirmed that nginx works properly in the ec2 instance

```
sudo yum install nginx -y

sudo systemctl enable nginx
sudo systemctl start nginx
curl http://localhost
```

Step 6 –
Removed the server block from the nginx.conf
Created a new “dotnetcore.conf” in /etc/nginx/conf.d folder

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   _;
 
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000/weatherforecast;
    }
}
```

Step 7 –
Restarted nginx

```
sudo nginx -t
sudo nginx -s reload
```

Step 8 –
Ran below command at the prompt

```
curl http://localhost
```

But I get error page with 502 Bad gateway

```
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that request received by backend service or it is failing at Nginx ? I hope this link will help you https://medium.com/@mshanak/solve-nginx-error-signin-oidc-502-bad-gateway-dotnet-core-and-identity-serve-bc27920b42d5

Comment: I think it's failing in nginx. It's not able to reach the dot net service